# How to detect the language of a document - in PHP?

Tags: php, language-detection

The basics have already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257125/human-language-of-a-document). But is there a pre-built PHP lib doing the same as Lingua::Identify from CPAN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a PEAR package [`Text_LanguageDetect`](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_LanguageDetect) that I've used before. Get's the job done well enough. I'm not sure of any other libs that are more mature.

Comment: it's compatible with php 7.1

Answer (score 0):

1- You could do it yourself (the hard way) - detecting both language and codepage by looking at character and n-gram frequencies. You would need lots of "training" data, but it's doable.

2- You could run a perl script to do the detection for you(much easier).

Comment: How do you do it in Perl exactly?

Comment: I should have explained more... "There's a module for that!" use Lingua::Ident ...