# Test the language of input data

Tags: php, language-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect language from string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441562/detect-language-from-string-in-php)

I want to do a test on the language of input data. For example: if the user sends data in one other language (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, ...) an error message appears asking him to enter this data in English.

Comment: Will this data be coming in as UTF-8? You mention that the user is sending data, so I am guessing that this won't be direct input from the user.

Comment: Look this ["How to detect the language of a document - in PHP?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290851/how-to-detect-the-language-of-a-document-in-php), especially accepted answer.

Comment: [How to detect language of text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752691/how-to-detect-language-of-text) is also pretty close.

Comment: example if the user enters the text: 你好 or مرحبا ... for this <input name="test" type="text"  id="numero" value="{$test}"/> an error message appears. The value of $test must be in English

Comment: To be more precise this is what I want to do for example if the user :testهذه هي بعض النصوص العربية  an error message appears

Comment: here's a simple solution I test the ASCII code of character entered:

<pre><code> 
        <?php

        function testText() {


            if (isset($_POST["textTst"])) {

                $test = $_POST["textTst"];

                for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($test); $i++) {

                    if (!in_array(ord($test[$i]), range(35, 127)))
                        return "Please re-sign the text in English ";
                }

                return "Successful message";
            }

            return "Input text is empty";
        }
        ?>

</code> 

what do you think
cordially
Kohan

Comment: sorry i don't know how can i format my code with stackoverflow :-(

Comment: I do not know why you close my topic?!!!!!!!!!! it's a Duplicate

Comment: hello

Please can you open my topic? because I do not believe that it is a duplicate
thank you in advance for your rethinks

cordially
Kohan